# Can I connect to a custom Parse server using Parse4J or something similar in a Java web app?

Tags: java, rest, maven, spring-boot, parse-server

Is there any way to connect my database hosted at Back4App (www.back4app.com) to Java web application using Springboot? I saw this library: https://github.com/thiagolocatelli/parse4j, but it doesn't seem to support connecting to a custom server URI at the moment. Do you guys have a solution?

First, I included their Maven dependency:

```
<project ...>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.thiagolocatelli</groupId>
            <artifactId>parse4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

And just when I pasted the initialization method I noticed it doesn't actually support that third parameter yet:

```
Parse.initialize(APP_ID, APP_REST_API_ID, CUSTOM_SERVER_PATH);
```

Is anyone aware of an existing library to handle this for a Java web application (I'm using Springboot)?

Comment: Hey, 

at the moment the Parse.initialize does not accept four variables. I recommend you work with the option to make HTTP Requests,using REST API.

Comment: @nataliec I managed to get this running by using their version ``1.5-SNAPSHOT``. I had to build the jar locally and put it in my local maven repo myself. See here: https://github.com/thiagolocatelli/parse4j/issues/81

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the information, it's really nice to know :)

Comment: @nataliec No problem! I just wish this project was not so outdated. You may actually have better luck building a web app in .NET/C# if you prefer not to use JavaScript. See here for more info: https://github.com/parse-community/Parse-SDK-dotNET. I'm building one now.

Comment: I'll read more about it, thank you! I built one in Ruby, I found it very interesting :)
Thank you for your attention!